# VBA & HTML Objects - click invisible dropdown

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-8, html-object

I'm trying to trigger the event `main.filaPopupV3_1.select('alta');` via VBA in IE8

The dropdown `main.filaPopupV3_1` is invisible until another button is clicked. I can get the dropdown to become visible but i can't access any of the options in it.

```
'alta'
```

Is one of the options i want to click.

Thats my code which isn't working.

```
'IE References at start are
Set myIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
Set Document = myIE.Document
```

I skip the navigation etc.

```
    Document.getElementById("BViewElementCSSIcon5").FireEvent ("onmouseover")
    Document.getElementById("BViewElementCSSIcon5").FireEvent ("onclick")
    Document.getElementById("main_filaPopupV3_1_main_filaPopupV3_1_root").FireEvent ("onmouseover")
    Document.getElementById ("main.filaPopupV3_1._cancelHide=1;")
    Document.getElementById ("main.filaPopupV3_1.hideMenu('alta');event.cancelBubble=true;")
    Document.getElementById("main.filaPopupV3_1('alta')").FireEvent ("onmouseover")
    Document.getElementById ("main.filaPopupV3_1.select('alta');")
    Document.getElementById("alta").Click
```

I know that some lines are unnecassary. Thats just me trying so far

[HTML source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7DJa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer but if someone could explain **why** this is working, i'd be very happy. Thanks

```
myIE.Navigate ("javascript:main.filaPopupV3_1.select('alta');")
```